# Merge XML attributes for output

Tags: xml, powershell

I would like to create a txt file report about installed products. I get these information from an XML document with the following structure:

```
<xmlroot>
 <product definitionName="ProductName" versionMajor="1" versionMinor="1" versionBuild="111">
 </product>
```

Now, after I filtered by definitionName, I want to write a file with two colomns "ProductName" and "Version" by concatenating the versions like this "1.1.111".

When I do this:

```
$ProductVersions.xmlroot.product | Select-Object -Property definitionName, versionMajor,     versionMinor, versionBuild
```

I get a list like this:

```
definitionName                                  versionMajor                                   versionMinor                                    versionBuild                                  
--------------                                  ------------                                   ------------                                    ------------                                  
ProductName                                     1                                               1                                               111
```

What I want is a list like this:

```
ProductName                                   Version                          
--------------                                ------------                              
ProductName                                   1.1.111
```

Please help me to find a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PS C:\> $ProductVersions.xmlroot.product |
 Select-Object -Property @{n='ProductName';e={$_.definitionName}}, @{n='Version';e={"$($_.versionMajor).$($_.versionMinor).$($_.versionBuild)"}}

ProductName                                                               Version                                                                 
-----------                                                               -------                                                                 
ProductName                                                               1.1.111
```

Slightly cleaner version suggested by @Ansgar Wiechars:

```
PS C:\> $ProductVersions.xmlroot.product |
 Select-Object -Property @{n='ProductName';e={$_.definitionName}},
  @{n='Version';e={"{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $_.versionMajor, $_.versionMinor, $_.versionBuild}}

ProductName                                                               Version                                                                 
-----------                                                               -------                                                                 
ProductName                                                               1.1.111
```

Comment: You could also use the format operator instead of subexpressions: `"{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $_.versionMajor, $_.versionMinor, $_.versionBuild`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I've added that version to my answer.